# Javascript physics get current mouse X coordinate

Tags: javascript, mouse, physics, coordinate

I've been asked (as a school exercise) to search information on the net about Physics library, or somehow find a way to create Arkanoid game and put it inside a website homepage.

I created the rectangles I need to blast using canvas etc, now I have to create the lower rectangle, that has Y coordinate 400, and X coordinate Cursor X coordinate, and I need to do this inline (not inside a function).
How do I achieve this?

(Now I can't paste any part of my code because I'm not home right now, I'll do it as soon as I can)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your mouse position in a global var and then use it where you need it:

```
var mouse = {x:0, y:0};
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    mouse.x = event.pageX;
    mouse.y = event.pageY;
});
```

---

(Add the event to your canvas if you need a specific position inside that element)

```
var mouse = {x:0, y:0};
document.getElementById("myCanvas").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
});
```

Now you can just call `mouse.x` or `mouse.y` to get the coordinate you need

Comment: Great! As soon as I can I'll test it and let you know! Thank you.

Comment: Your code is working great, but I have just a problem. If I output mouseX or mouseY inside function(event) { etc... it outputs the right coordinate, but if I output them outside the function it prints 0 at anytime! How do I make the new value sticky?
Thank you!

Comment: if it's always 0 maybe it's because `mouse` hasn't changed, it is still using  the default values `var mouse = {x:0, y:0}` , where did you use that variable  and how